# Problem regarding messagebox module in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm, tkmessagebox

My message box launches automatically without me clicking the button first when I run it in Pycharm.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title('Frame')
root.iconbitmap('D:\Tkinter\Frame.ico')


def popup():
    messagebox.showinfo("Popup","You have clicked a button!")

Button(root, text = 'Click Me!',commmand=popup()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[And this is what I get when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEonY.png)

Comment: Read [Why is parameter “command=” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Answer (score 0):

In Button declaration, you are calling your function instead of passing a callback to it.

There is also a typo in a word 'command' - you wrote it with 3x m.

So, you should declare your button as:

```
Button(root, text = 'Click Me!',command=popup).pack()
```

[How to create a basic button](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm)

Comment: I tried it but this the error I get when I run the code.

_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-commmand"

Comment: Same results man  -_-

Comment: I copy pasted your code and then only changed it instead of pasting my own working snippet. You had also a typo - you wrote 'command' with 3x ms - 'commmand' instead of 'command'.